# Simple HTML ruler double spacing fix

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a very simple ruler in HTML but I have a problem in the spacing when I add more numeric characters where it doubles e.g., notice the spacing after (10). Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Also I would appreciate if there is a better simple idea on how to achieve the same.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qx0h22tj/

```html
<table style="width: 920px; font-family: monospace;">
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
        <td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td width="1%">
            |
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            0
        </td><td>
            1
        </td><td>
            2
        </td><td>
            3
        </td><td>
            4
        </td><td>
            5
        </td><td>
            6
        </td><td>
            7
        </td><td>
            8
        </td><td>
            9
        </td><td>
            10
        </td><td>
            11
        </td><td>
            12
        </td><td>
            13
        </td><td>
            14
        </td><td>
            15
        </td><td>
            16
        </td><td>
            17
        </td><td>
            18
        </td><td>
            19
        </td><td>
            20
        </td><td>
            21
        </td><td>
            22
        </td><td width="1%">
            23
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `table-layout: fixed` to `<table>`

**CSS**

```
table{
     table-layout: fixed;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/qx0h22tj/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Does using `table-layout:fixed;` solve your problem?

```css
table{table-layout:fixed;}
```

```html
<table style="width: 920px; font-family: monospace;">
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
        <td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td>
            |
        </td><td width="1%">
            |
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            0
        </td><td>
            1
        </td><td>
            2
        </td><td>
            3
        </td><td>
            4
        </td><td>
            5
        </td><td>
            6
        </td><td>
            7
        </td><td>
            8
        </td><td>
            9
        </td><td>
            10
        </td><td>
            11
        </td><td>
            12
        </td><td>
            13
        </td><td>
            14
        </td><td>
            15
        </td><td>
            16
        </td><td>
            17
        </td><td>
            18
        </td><td>
            19
        </td><td>
            20
        </td><td>
            21
        </td><td>
            22
        </td><td width="1%">
            23
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```